# Cannot change Widget's div background color with CSS when using "class"

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget

I am developing a widget for Windows desktop. When displaying my data, I have the following code in JavaScript:

```
var data = ...;
output += " <div class=\"col-md well\" style=\"background-color:green;\"> " + data + "</div>";
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = output;
```

where "demo" is a div in my HTML code. 
The problem is that the color doesn't work together with the class. When I have the "class" specifier, the color doesn't change. It only changes when I don't use "class" in my div. Any ideas?

Comment: is `col-md` a class? try `col-md-12`. Also, try `background-color:green !important;`

Comment: Without seeing the CSS it's hard to say.  But is sounds like "class" is taking precedence over the inline style.

Comment: try adding: `background:green !important;` (sometimes `background` and `background-color` conflict)

Comment: @durbnpoisn This is what I observe too. I don't have any other CSS, it's only this one.

Comment: @Hybrid Thanks for your advice. I tried it all but the problem persists.

Comment: Does the JS which assigns the html to the demo element come after your bootstrap stylesheet is called? Put the <script> before you link to the stylesheet.

Comment: Could it be that the 'data' contains a block level element that changes bgcolor with one of those parent classes? If running in a browser, you might check out the inspector to check which item overrides it.